# ui.router REDIRECTION - getting wrong data object on toState

Tags: angularjs, redirect, angular-ui-router, state

User that is not authenticated is redirected to login page.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState)
```

toState is running twice, as expected but the last run is the destination run and not the login page data. see the code below.

Index:

```
<section ng-if="page.header" ng-class="{'transparent-header': page.transparentHeader}" user-header></section>
```

**Controller:**

```
.controller('appController', ['$scope','$state','$rootScope', function($scope,$state,$rootScope){

    //Control header and footer views getting data from router
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){

        $scope.page = toState.data;

    })




}]);
```

**Redirection:**

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'userService', '$sessionStorage', function($rootScope, $state, userService, $sessionStorage){

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart'
    , function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

    //Detecting sessions
    if($sessionStorage.userData){
        var goodORnot = $sessionStorage.userData.isLogged;
    }else{
        goodORnot = false;
    }

    var isAuthenticationRequired =  toState.data 
          && toState.data.requiresLogin 
          //&& !userService.isLogged
          && !goodORnot
      ;

    if(isAuthenticationRequired)
    {
      event.preventDefault();
      $state.go('LoginPage');
    }
  });
}]);
```

**Console log:**

```
Object {name: "Login", header: false, footer: false, css: false, transparentHeader: false}

Object {name: "Your Profile", header: true, footer: false, css: true, transparentHeader: true…}
```

How to prevent the **toState** to run again? if the redirection occurs i don't want the toState from the controller to run, or how i overwrite it?